# Antivirus for Windows 2008 Operating System

Tags: windows-server-2008, anti-virus

Is there any antivirus(preferably McAfee) software for a PC running on Windows 2008 server edition?

I google but could not find out a right antivirus that runs on Windows 2008. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Win2008 Workstation](http://www.win2008workstation.com/) the forums there maybe able to help you. But be aware of license violations.....

When I ran the server edition on my laptop (for HyperV) I was using Avast 4.x versions [I have since switched back to Win7 as the VM's now run on another machine]

Now if you are after a true AV solution for a true server, then there are many AV's that run on the server if you are prepared to pay for that licensing (in no particular order):

- [Kaspersky](http://www.kaspersky.com/anti-virus_windows_server)
- [Avast](http://www.avast.com/server-edition)
- [Eset](http://www.eset.com/company/article/eset-announces-support-for-windows-server-2008/4470.php?contentid=4470)
- [Avira](http://www.avira.com/en/products/avira_antivir_server_3.html)
- [Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/business/products/sysreq.jsp?pcid=pcat_security&pvid=805_1)
- [CA](http://www.ca.com/us/products/product.aspx?id=156)
- [McAfee](http://www.mcafee.com/us/enterprise/products/system_security/servers/virusscan_enterprise.html)
- [Sophos](http://www.sophos.com/products/enterprise/endpoint/security-and-control/windows/sysreqs.html)

All that in a 5 minute [qrobe.it](http://qrobe.it/search/?q=windows+server+antivirus+support&s=sb) websearch.....